# kotlin fun main(args : Array<String>) doesn't work in command line

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin 1.3.30 I just installed, the main entry function doesn't work in command line. JDK is version 8. Intellij Idea is 2019.1.1. No dependency, very clean project.

When I started learning Kotlin, the main entry is 'fun main(args: Array)'. Last year, 'fun main()' could be used without 'args' and I used it a lot.
Now I have a project needs command line parameters, but something goes wrong. I've tried 3 formats:

```
// 1. doesn't work.
fun main(vararg args: String){
    println("this is a test.")
}

// 2. doesn't work
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println("this is a test.")
}

// 3. this works. but where can I get the command line parameters?
fun main(){
    println("this is a test.")
}
```

1 & 2 has same response:

```
λ java -jar test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.yxy.ProgramFileKt.main(ProgramFile.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

It works fine with 3 without changing any other thing. But I need command line args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the exception, your jar does not contain the Kotlin stdlib. You need to slightly modify your build.

Adding something like this to your Gradle build should fix it:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0"
}
```

P.S. This error is very common and has little to do with the `main` function. Try googling the error message.

Comment: ... that however wouldn't explain why `main` without parameters did work... except... there was some stdlib there and now it isn't?

Comment: @Roland it does, if you have a look at Intrinsics (https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java) there are a lot of checks, which probably skipped it main has no args and therefore main without runs without stdlib

Comment: Most probably once it encountered the Array or String types in the function declaration, it tried to look for it in the stdlib and couldn't find the stdlib.

Comment: Before upgrade to newest IDEA & Kotlin, ```compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"``` is added automatically and everything is fine.
But with the newest version, ```implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"``` was added only.
Manual add kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 which include stdlib works.